# Media sync (MTP) not working on LG G2 LS980

Tags: lg-g2, media-files

I recently did whatever possible to run "Google Now" on my LG G2 LS980. I updated Google App, installed Google Now, fiddled with don't-remember-how-many settings.

I made it (but not as expected). But as a side effect, the **Media Sync (MTP)** is not working on the phone. Means, whenever I connect my phone to a PC / laptop, my phone doesn't show up in the Windows Explorer.

Just in case, the settings are as under :
Settings > PC Connection > Select USB Connection  Method > Media Sync (MTP)

My phone is a rooted one, running on Android 4.4.2 custom ROM.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall LGE Mobile USB Composite Driver (don't forget tick Delete driver software). [image: figure1 unistall driver]

Plugin your LG Phone via USB then click "scan check for hardware changes"
Then,,,enjoy ;)